# Why can't my Python codes plot diagram to the designated directory?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, plotly, openpyxl

1.Purpose: Select an xlsx file to read data from. Then choose a directory to place the result. The codes are supposed to work after you press the button "Step3:Start to plot".

[image: UI of the code]

2. Raw data:

```
             1991  1992  1993  1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999
         US    10    14    16    18    20    42    64   100    50
      JAPAN   100    30    70    85    30    42    64    98    24
         CN    50    22    30    65    70    66    60    45    45
      INDIA    90    88    35    50    90    60    40    66    76
         UK    40    50    70    50    25    30    22    40    60
```

3. My solution:
   (1)P201.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import bubble3
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn_file = tk.Button(self, text="Step1:Import data from", command=self.choose_file)
        btn_dir = tk.Button(self, text="Step2:Export diagram to",
                            command=self.choose_directory)
        btn_start = tk.Button(self, text="Step3:Start to plot", command=self.start)
        btn_file.pack(padx=60, pady=10)
        btn_dir.pack(padx=60, pady=10)
        btn_start.pack(padx=60, pady=10)

    def choose_file(self):
        filetypes = (("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
                     )
        filename = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open file",
                                      initialdir="/", filetypes=filetypes)
        if filename:
            print(filename)

    def choose_directory(self):
        directory = fd.askdirectory(title="Open directory",
                                    initialdir="/")
        if directory:
            print(directory)

    def start(self):
        bubble3.SP(app.filename, app.directory)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

(2)bubble3.py

```
# Version 2
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os


def SP(input_file, output_dir):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file)
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    row_max = sheet.max_row
    col_max = sheet.max_column
    first_row_list = []
    first_col_list = []
    for col_n in range(2, col_max+1):
        first_row_list.append(sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_n).value)
    for row_n in range(2,row_max+1):
        first_col_list.append(sheet.cell(row=row_n, column=1).value)

    data_all = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    data_selected = data_all.loc[:,first_row_list]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_selected)
    df.index = first_col_list
    colors = ['rgb(150,204,90)','rgb(255, 130, 71)','rgb(255, 193, 37)','rgb(180,240,190)','rgb(255, 10, 1)',
              'rgb(25, 19, 3)','rgb(100, 100, 100)','rgb(45,24,200)','rgb(33, 58, 108)','rgb(35, 208, 232)']

    data = [go.Scatter(
        x=df.columns,
        y=[country]*len(df.columns),
        mode='markers+text',
        marker=dict(
            color=colors[num],
            size= df.loc[country],
            showscale = False,
            ),
        text=list(map(str, df.loc[country])),
        textposition='middle center',
        )
        for num, country in enumerate(reversed(df.index))
    ]

    layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor='rgb(10, 10, 10)',
                       paper_bgcolor='rgb(20, 55, 100)',
                       font={
                           'size': 15,
                           'family': 'sans-serif',
                           'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
                       },
                       width=1000,
                       height=800,
                       xaxis=dict(
                           title='Output of grapes per year in different countries',
                           nticks = col_max+1,
                           type = 'category',
                       ),
                       showlegend=False,
                       margin=dict(l=100, r=100, t=100, b=100),
                       hovermode = False,
                       )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.offline.plot(fig, filename=os.path.join(output_dir,'bubble_diagram.html'))
```

4. Problem: Codes don't seem to work properly since no result could be found.
   Please shed light on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the error in my code. The attributes "filename" and "directory" of the two methods choose_file() and choose_directory() should be given a prefix "self.". Now the program runs perfectly.
Here is the corrected code:(two files have been combined to one)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn_file = tk.Button(self, text="Step1:Import data from", command=self.choose_file)
        btn_dir = tk.Button(self, text="Step2:Set output path",
                            command=self.choose_directory)
        btn_start = tk.Button(self, text="Step3:Start to plot", command=self.start)
        btn_file.pack(padx=60, pady=10)
        btn_dir.pack(padx=60, pady=10)
        btn_start.pack(padx=60, pady=10)

    def choose_file(self):
        filetypes = (("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
                     )
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open file",
                                      initialdir="/", filetypes=filetypes)
        if self.filename:
            print(self.filename)

    def choose_directory(self):
        self.directory = fd.askdirectory(title="Open directory",
                                    initialdir="/")
        if self.directory:
            print(self.directory)

    def start(self):
        self.SP(self.filename, self.directory)


    def SP(self, input_file, output_dir):
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.input_file)
        sheet = wb['Sheet1']
        row_max = sheet.max_row
        col_max = sheet.max_column
        first_row_list = []
        first_col_list = []
        for col_n in range(2, col_max+1):
            first_row_list.append(sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_n).value)
        for row_n in range(2,row_max+1):
            first_col_list.append(sheet.cell(row=row_n, column=1).value)

        data_all = pd.read_excel(self.input_file)
        data_selected = data_all.loc[:,first_row_list]

        df = pd.DataFrame(data_selected)
        df.index = first_col_list
        colors = ['rgb(150,204,90)','rgb(255, 130, 71)','rgb(255, 193, 37)','rgb(180,240,190)','rgb(255, 10, 1)',
                  'rgb(25, 19, 3)','rgb(100, 100, 100)','rgb(45,24,200)','rgb(33, 58, 108)','rgb(35, 208, 232)']

        data = [go.Scatter(
            x=df.columns,
            y=[country]*len(df.columns),
            mode='markers+text',
            marker=dict(
                color=colors[num],
                size= df.loc[country],
                showscale = False,
                ),
            text=list(map(str, df.loc[country])),
            textposition='middle center',
            )
            for num, country in enumerate(reversed(df.index))
        ]

        layout = go.Layout(plot_bgcolor='rgb(10, 10, 10)',
                           paper_bgcolor='rgb(20, 55, 100)',
                           font={
                               'size': 15,
                               'family': 'sans-serif',
                               'color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
                           },
                           width=1000,
                           height=800,
                           xaxis=dict(
                               title='Output of grapes per year in different countries',
                               nticks = col_max+1,
                               type = 'category',
                           ),
                           showlegend=False,
                           margin=dict(l=100, r=100, t=100, b=100),
                           hovermode = False,
                           )

        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        py.offline.plot(fig, filename=os.path.join(self.output_dir,'bubble_diagram.html'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```